# Why PhpStorm don't recognizes $.post method?

Tags: jquery, ide, phpstorm

The PhpStorm don't recognizes a `$.post` method:

[image]

I'm using Jquery 1.9.1!

What do I need to setup or what am I doing wrong?

Here is my `menu.js`:

```
(function( Menu, $, undefined ) {
    // propriedade que armazena id do menu
    var menu_id;

    // Métodos públicos
    Menu.init = function(_menu_id) {
        menu_id = _menu_id;

        // preenchendo evento 'tree.move'
        menuObj.bind('tree.move', function(event) {
                var ordem;

                // here i get the changes in 'event' param and put in 'ordem'

                // save
                salvarOrdemItens(JSON.stringify(ordem));
            }
        );
    };

    function salvarOrdemItens(mudancasMenu) {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(mudancasMenu));
        $.post('/administrativo/menu/salvar-ordem-item/'+menu_id,
                { "mudancasMenus" : mudancasMenu }
        );
    }
}( window.Menu = window.Menu || {}, jQuery ));
```

Comment: Is jQuery loaded before you try to use it?  Does this result in an actual runtime error, or just an IDE warning?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by phpStorm doesn't recognize `$.post`? are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: @David, no runtime error (just a tooltip: unresolved function or method post())

Comment: @kevin-b, just a IDE warning

Comment: I see menu_id declared but never given a value. perhaps this has something to do with it?  Also what do you mean by not recognizing it? are you getting a specific error? if so please list the error

Comment: oh you mean your intellisense isn't detecting it as valid? Have you tried to use it on the page or are you jsut assuming since your ide is telling you it doesnt recognize it that you cant use it?

Comment: @daniel-ward, my intellisense isn't detecting it as valid. there is only a IDE warning (see image). other jquery methods are shown in intellisense. '$.ajax' completes, for example...

Comment: @DanielWard, i've updated the code. i've put the 'init' with 'menu_id' fill (before I had omitted)

Comment: Could you try "File | Invalidate caches..." in case you have not done it yet? I have jQuery library next to the file (in a subfolder) and your file .. and it works (no error is shown) -- tried in both v6.0.3 and v7 EAP.

Comment: @LazyOne, great solution.. do you wanna to create an "official answer"? (and if possible to explain what to do this "Invalidate cach")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem:

"File" > "Invalidate caches"

> More info about this command: http://goo.gl/h6IRYB

Thanks to @lazyone.

Comment: Found this wondering why with version 8 the symbol $ was Invalid and this fixed my issue, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Invalidating caches didn't work for me but downloading an uncompressed/un-minified  version of jQuery and including it in my project did.

https://code.jquery.com/jquery/

I also went to the following section in settings and added the uncompressed jQuery file

```
Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries
```

Comment: If you have the minified version in your project for actual production use this will gain you multiple sources. So put the unminified version in a "stub" folder and your minified version in a "prod" folder and exclude the prod folder at Settings/Preferences => Directories => {navigate to folder} => Exclude

Answer (score 0):

Mark your public (public_html, web) folder as Document Root.

Comment: I found a tutorial (http://goo.gl/inbssS) that shows how to setup a "Project Root", but my 6.0.3 version doesn't have this button. It has Test, Resource and Excluded. I marked my static folder as resource root and doesn't work yet.